# how to send response in koa.js with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

how to send response in koa.js with node?
in below example I want to send the response with proper status code and message but below example didn't send anything.

```
    let user = await User.findOne({mobile:ctx.request.body.mobile});
    if(user){
        ctx.status = 400;
        ctx.message = "Already Exist";
    }else{
        let userData = await new User(ctx.request.body).save();
        ctx.status = 200;
        ctx.message = "User Registered Success"
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your Koa code. Are you sure your queries are working properly?

Comment: when i hit the api from postman this code give the message  "User Registered Success" only. but i want status code message and req.body in the response with genrated id

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain what exactly it is that you want?

Comment: {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "User Registered Successfully",
    "data": {
        "name": "Akshay",
        "age": 24,
        "mobile": 434844457384,
        "email": "akshayudapure5@gmail.com",
        "password": "AWS123",
        "_id": "633d1794e35f4c9c6da60e70"
    }
}

Comment: i want output like this when i hit the API from postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass an object to `ctx.body` it will be returned as JSON:

```
ctx.body = {
  status:  200,
  message: 'User Registered Successfully',
  data:    userData
};
```

Comment: thank you so much robertklep its giving proper output